# How do I download information stored in my Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a Chrome extension where the workflow looks like:

- user browses the internet and can save links. I have a strong preferences to store all links locally instead of, say, having to talk to an external server.
- user can then hit a button in the extension which generates and downloads a csv file of all the saved links so far

Two questions:

1. What is the appropriate way to store this data over multiple sessions?
2. What is the appropriate way of generating the file and prompting a download?

For 1, I plan on using `chrome.storage.local`.

For 2, it's unclear what the best way is. I'm considering writing the data to options.html or popup.html, then calling `chrome.downloads` to download that page, but it feels like a massive hack.

What is the correct way of doing 1 and 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Using `chrome.storage.local` is the right way here.
2. I am using this snippet right from the popup in order to save text/json/csv files:

```js
/**
 * @param data {String} what to save
 * @param extension {String} file extension
 */
function saveFile(data, extension = 'json') {
    const fileName = `export-file.${extension}`;

    const textFileAsBlob = new Blob([data], {type: 'text/plain'});
    const downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
    downloadLink.download = fileName;

    downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
    downloadLink.target = '_blank';
    downloadLink.click();

    return fileName;
}
```

It will save a file to disk. And it is not a hacky way.

**Update for #2**

Another way is to pass base64 URL to the downloads API:

```
chrome.downloads.download({url: 'data:image/gif;base64,SEVMTE8gV09STEQh', filename: 'test.txt'})
```

Comment: Why use an anchor element instead of `chrome.downloads.download({url, filename})` ?

Comment: @Jean-Alphonse, the background story is that I had to have the same implementation for a website and extension. So I am using this snippet for many years. But yeah, you also can pass base64url: `chrome.downloads.download({url: 'data:image/gif;base64,SEVMTE8gV09STEQh', filename: 'test.txt'})`

Comment: Ah okay. In that case `url: URL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob)` should work as well.